# Javascript selecting part of a string and converting it to uppercase

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this:

```
A sampletext
b sampletext3
c exampletext    
A sampletext587
b sampletext5
b sampletextasdf
d sampletext4
b sometext
c sampletextrandom
```

How do I, in JS, convert all the text on the lines starting with `b` to upper case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regex

```
"b sampletext3".replace(/^b/gm,function(x){return x.toUpperCase()})
B sampletext3
```

And assigning it to String Object

```
String.prototype.toTitleCaseB=function(){
    return this.replace(/^b/gm,function(x){return x.toUpperCase()})
}
```

Would later use like

```
"b sampletext3".toTitleCaseB()
B sampletext3
```

Comment: yeah, I overlooked some part of the question, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

1. `split` the string on `\n`
2. loop over the resulting array
3. use `substring` to extract the first letter and test it
4. optionally set the array item to itself.`toUpperCase()`
5. `join` the array